# Django TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: django

I'm getting the following error:

**TypeError: 'int' object is not callable**

**response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/LiveWireSMS/sms/models/message.py", line 156, in my_handler
    instance.charge = instance.length(instance.content)**

From this snippet of code:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Message)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    if not instance.charge:
        instance.charge = instance.length(instance.content)
```

This is the function its calling:

```
@property
def length(self):
    return len(self.content) / 160 + 1
```

Could someone explain the error? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got this error because `length` returns an `int` object and you tried to call it.

```
instance.charge = instance.length # instead of instance.length(instance.content)
```